# MS CRM 2011: How to get the associated entity-name for a privilege

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I'm retrieving a list of all privileges from CRM:

```
QueryExpression q = new QueryExpression("privilege") {ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(true)};

var list = service.RetrieveMultiple(q).Entities;
```

This works fine.

I would now like to know the entity-name every privilege applies to. I.e. the privilege "prvDeleteNote" applies to the entity "Note".

This is no problem querying the database with SQL directly, but I would much prefer to retrieve the information from a service.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, this FetchXML returns what I was looking for:

```
<fetch mapping=""logical"" version=""1.0"">
                        <entity name=""privilege"">
                            <attribute name=""privilegeid"" />
                            <attribute name=""name"" />
                            <attribute name=""canbelocal"" />                                
                            <attribute name=""canbedeep"" />
                            <attribute name=""canbeglobal"" />
                            <attribute name=""canbebasic"" />                                
                            <link-entity name=""privilegeobjecttypecodes"" from=""privilegeid"" to=""privilegeid"" link-type=""outer"" alias=""otc"">                    
                                <attribute name=""objecttypecode"" />
                            </link-entity>
                        </entity>
                        </fetch>
```

I can access the Type with:

```
((AliasedValue)privilegeEntity.Attributes["otc.objecttypecode"]).Value.ToString()
```

where privilegeEntity is one entity from the response.

I was expecting the int value ObjectTypeCode, and was suprised that it returns the name of the entity.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know `privilege` entity doesn't have a property to identity the related entity.